# How to use cd in another mounted harddisk?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, removable-storage

Talking about the 105 GB volume. I want to search in it through terminal using locate/find.

That is already mounted. When I right click, I get unmount in the menu.

***How do I enter that area through terminal?***

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Normally, (automatically) mounted drives are in `/media`. So, to `cd` into your drive you would:

```
cd /media/<device name>
```

The same applies to other commands, e.g.:

```
find /media/<device name>/
```

Read more **[here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26775/access-mounted-volumes-via-the-command-line)**.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on where the drive is mounted, it is common for drives that are automounted by guis to be placed in `/media/...`. You can confirm exactly where by running `mount` which will list all mounted drives along with where they are mounted. Once you know this location simply `cd /path/that/mount/showed`.

Answer (score 0):

The command [`lsblk`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/lsblk.8.html) lists block devices (i.e. storage devices such as hard disks, CD, etc. and the partitions and other subvolumes on them) in a relatively convenient way. Look in that list for a volume with a size of about 105GB. The right-hand column lists the mount point, i.e. the place where the hard disk is attached in the filesystem hierarchy. So if that column lists e.g. `/media/mydisk` then the full path to files on that disk start with `/media/mydisk/` and you can use

```
cd /media/mydisk
```

in a shell to change to the toplevel directory of that disk.